# Python : Explode rows from panda dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, range, explode

im new to Python and i'm working on panda dataframe.

So I have a dataframe like:

```
Client_id   Nb_Products
1           2
2           3
3           1
```

And I need to explode each row *Nb_Products* times for each *client_id*.
So i need to output the following  table:

```
Client_id   Product_Nb
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           2
2           3
3           1
```

At first i think i should create a range of numbers for *Nb_Products* like :

```
Client_id   Nb_Products_rng
1           [1,2]
2           [1,2,3]
3           [1]
```

And then explode it.
But i couldn't succeed creating this.

I'll be greatful to any answer or part of answer. 
Thank you

Comment: I personally hate the idea of putting lists in a pandas `dataframe` for things like this - I see it all the time and it isn't necessary here either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Methodology

I use an index firstly to speed things up and get the unique client ids

```
df = df.set_index('Client_id')
client_ids = df.index.get_level_values('Client_id').unique()
```

Then I just reconstruct the DataFrame by iterating over all products per client

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [client, prod]
        for client in client_ids
        for prod in range(1, df.loc[client, 'Nb_Products'].max()+1)
    ],
    columns = ['Client_id', 'Nb_Products']
)
```

## Example / Test

The test data I used

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]],
    columns=['Client_id', 'Nb_Products']
)
```

Initial DataFrame

```
   Client_id  Nb_Products
0          1            2
1          2            3
2          3            3
```

Result

```
   Client_id  Nb_Products
0          1            1
1          1            2
2          2            1
3          2            2
4          2            3
5          3            1
6          3            2
7          3            3
```

Comment: Are you sure the output matches the OP's requirement? Isn't that returning the same dataframe instead

Comment: @ClockSlave This returns exactly what i needed. Thank you for your help i will also try your suggestion and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by repeating the values in `Client_id` `Nb_products` time to 'explode' your dataset. Repeating `Client_id` value in a row by the the value against it in the `Nb_products` column will produce the `Client_id` variable of the new dataframe. I do this using list comprehension.

To get the second column - `Product_Nb` you simply need a sequence starting from 1.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""Client_id Nb_Products
1 2
2 3
3 1""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=" ")

col1 = []
_ = [col1.extend([a]*b) for a,b in zip(df.iloc[:,0].values.tolist(), df.iloc[:,1].values.tolist())]
col2 = []
_ = [col2.extend(list(range(1,i+1))) for i in df.iloc[:,1].values.tolist()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1,col2)),columns = ['Client_id', 'Product_Nb'])
```